# onReadyForSpeech() in Android speech recognition (SpeechRecognizer) never gets called

Tags: android, speech-recognition

Here's my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_route);

    SetupButton();

}

private void SetupButton()
{
    Button createNewMessage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    createNewMessage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ListenForNewMessage();
        }
    });
}

private void ListenForNewMessage()
{
    final SpeechRecognizer newDeliverySpeech = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
    RecognitionListener newDeliveryRecognitionListener = new RecognitionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params) {
            Log.d("SpeechListening","onReadyForSpeech");
        }
        @Override
        public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
            Log.d("SpeechListening","onBeginningOfSpeech");
        }

        @Override
        public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {
            //do nothing
        }

        @Override
        public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {
            //do nothing
        }

        @Override
        public void onEndOfSpeech() {
            Log.d("SpeechListening","onEndOfSpeech");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(int error) {
            //do nothing
        }

        @Override
        public void onResults(Bundle results) {
            ArrayList<String> userMessage;
            userMessage = results.getStringArrayList(RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
            PushNewDelivery(userMessage);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults) {
            //do nothing
        }

        @Override
        public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params) {
            //do nothing
        }
    };
    newDeliverySpeech.setRecognitionListener(newDeliveryRecognitionListener);
    if (newDeliverySpeech.isRecognitionAvailable(getApplicationContext()))
    {
        Log.d("SpeechListening","started listening hopefully");
        newDeliverySpeech.startListening(new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH));
    }
}
```

}

The problem is, only the **started listening hopefully** is logged, the `RecognitionListener` never has `onReadyForSpeech()` or any of its methods called.

details
details
details
details
Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are basically creating a new SpeechRecognizer object and register a new listener each time you click on the button. On top of that you create the SpeechRecognizer using the current Activity Context but you are actually using the Application context when calling: isRecognitionAvailable();

Try to create the SpeechRecognizer as a member object and register your listener when onCreate() is called. Also try to avoid using the Application context to avoid memory leaks.

Here is an example of how you should do it.

```
private SpeechRecognizer mDeliverySpeech;
private Intent mSpeechIntent;
private boolean mListening = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_route);

    SetupButton();
    SetupSpeechRecognizer();

    mSpeechIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);

    mSpeechIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE, "en");
    mSpeechIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, this.getPackageName());
    mSpeechIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    mSpeechIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 3);
}

private void SetupButton()
{
    Button createNewMessage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    createNewMessage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ListenForNewMessage();
        }
    });
}

private void SetupSpeechRecognizer() 
{
    mDeliverySpeech = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);

     RecognitionListener newDeliveryRecognitionListener = new RecognitionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params) {
            Log.d("SpeechListening","onReadyForSpeech");
        }
        @Override
        public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
            Log.d("SpeechListening","onBeginningOfSpeech");
        }

        @Override
        public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {
            //do nothing
        }

        @Override
        public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {
            //do nothing
        }

        @Override
        public void onEndOfSpeech() {
            Log.d("SpeechListening","onEndOfSpeech");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(int error) {
            //do nothing
        }

        @Override
        public void onResults(Bundle results) {
            ArrayList<String> userMessage;
            userMessage = results.getStringArrayList(RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
            PushNewDelivery(userMessage);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults) {
            //do nothing
        }

        @Override
        public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params) {
            //do nothing
        }
    };

    mDeliverySpeech.setRecognitionListener(newDeliveryRecognitionListener);
}

private void ListenForNewMessage()
{   
    if (mDeliverySpeech.isRecognitionAvailable(this) && !mListening)
    {
        Log.d("SpeechListening","started listening hopefully");

        mListening = true;

        mDeliverySpeech.startListening(mSpeechIntent);

        new CountDownTimer(5000, 5000) {
             public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {}

             public void onFinish() {
                 mDeliverySpeech.stopListening();
                 mListening = false;
             }
          }.start();
    }
}
```

Do not forget to properly handle the activity life cycle when working with listener to avoid memory leak.

Comment: Still doesn't work.

Thank you though, you're definitely right what I was doing was bad, as I was falling asleep last night I pretty much had this same thought but I forgot about it.

Comment: I found another recourse that sends out an external intent using startActivityForResult(intent), and it works fine. I don't like that the dialog that pops up has a Google logo, and I don't like that trying to use the actual SpeechRecognizer objects provided doesn't work for me, but whatever I guess